# Comparing two doubles for equality fails

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, double

This is very strange, and I don't have a minimal example showing it, because it is in the middle of a large piece of code, and I can't replicate it in example code.

I have an if statement:

```
    Dim TBC as Double: TBC = 0.10625
    Dim temp_g As Double: temp_g = Vol * USVol
    If TBC = temp_g Then
        ContinueCalculation = False
    ElseIf TBC > temp_g Then
        Stop 'you have an error.
    End If
```

`Vol` and `USVol` are globally defined variants. `Vol = 0.125`. `USVol = 0.85`.

```
0.85 * 0.125 = 0.10625
```

I expect the `TBC = temp_g` if statement to fire, and for the `ContinueCalculation = False` statement to be hit. Instead the code hits the `TBC > temp_g` condition and the code stops.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Not much we can really say without seeing the exact method that `Vol` and `USVol` gets and retain it's value. This may be a issue of scope - but I would add a `debug.print "Vol=" & Vol; "USVol=" & USVol` statement right above the If statement.

Comment: With those numbers I can not get it to do anything but return the correct If command.  Are you sure the variable equal what you think?

Comment: Thank you for the help.
I added a debug print statement

        `TBC=0.10625 temp_g=0.10625 Vol=0.125 USVol=0.85`

Comment: What do you do with `ContinueCalculation = False`?  If you step through the code as it runs, are you sure that the else is being selected and the error is not somewhere else?  Put `msgbox "Here"` before the `ContinueCalculation = False` line and see if you are in the right spot.  None of us are seeing what you are.

Comment: I minus-ed one from the other in the debug:
the difference is `1.38777878078145E-17`
and that is probably why. Gonna try fixing it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Issue

The issue here is of a technical mathematical nature. Computers cannot really do algebraic calculations instead they do a numeric calculation with a defined precision. That means the result may mathematically not be correct but pretty pretty pretty close to correct.

Therefore you can't compare floating point values for equality.

Values in computers are not 100 % precise. They are only precise up to a specific amount of digits. For example:

```
Number       Value
0.1          0.1 (of course)
float(.1)    0.100000001490116119384765625
double(.1)   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

Read [Comparing floating point numbers](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) or [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel) for more background information and how to handle this correctly.

---

#### Solution 1

So instead of testing for equality `If TBC = temp_g Then` test if their difference is smaller than a "small number" `10⁻ⁿ` that meets the precision criteria you make to consider these two equal.

For example you can use the following (where `n` is the amount of digits you need for precision to consider them as equal):

```
If (TBC - temp_g) ^ 2 < (10 ^ -n) ^ 2 Then
```

*Note that we need to square both sides to make sure there are no negative results.*

---

#### Solution 2

Alternatively you can round both values to a specific amount of digits to test for equality.

```
If Round(TBC, 5) = Round(temp_g, 5) Then
```

This will consider `TBC` equal `temp_g` if their first 5 digits are the same.

Comment: I don't get why I got a down vote on this answer. What's wrong here? I think this is a very common technique, and I would like to understand the issue with that answer. • Does anyone have an idea, I'm just trying to understand it.